# Sorting by an expression based on nested field values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a mapping like

```
{
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "entities": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "score": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

So, the index consists of documents having text (`content`) and a list of nested `entities`, each having a `name` and a `score` telling, say, how often an entity is mentioned in a document.
When I build a query, I could be interested in multiple entities, let's say, (`A and B or C`), meaning that I search for documents having either both `A` and `B` or just `C` (and I build my `query` accordingly). What I try to achieve in addition is to apply the same rules for sorting. By that I mean (let's imagine I sort my documents descending) that a score for ranking in the above-mentioned case should be calculated as `max( min(a.score, b.score), c.score)`. So, briefly, any `and` is converted to `min`, while any `or` becomes `max`. Let's say that building that expression is not an issue and is out of scope of my question. My question is how to map that expression with mins and maxes to the `sort` part of a `query`? Is it possible to achieve that without scripting? If not, how do I write the script?

Thanks in advance